# Add barcodes to CSV list

Tags: product-attribute, products, csv, pos

I have 7000 products ready to sell, however I'm going to link it up to a POS system so I can sell instore and online. Therefore I need to assign all my internal stock codes a barcode. What's the quickest way to do this?

Comment: If the barcode value **is** the internal stock code, there is no need for any assignment, simply use the internal stock code as barcode. Or do you mean to create and print the barcode, using the internal stock code as its value?

Comment: My CSV list has no barcode information. However all my products in the physical shop have barcode labels already. Is it possible to scan the bar code and assign its value to each product in the CSV list? I do not wish to create a new barcode for all products.

Comment: off topic but here you go. Barcode scanners most of the time are just keyboards which fill in a number and press enter. So if you would do this in a Excelsheet with a moble barcode scanner, it would fill in a field and jump to the next line. So if you would export all sku's from Magento and scan the barcode in the second column it would create a list with sku, barcode